# Change the color of the text in list item Text

Tags: reactjs, web-deployment, styling, text-styling

I'm trying to change the color of my text of the ListItem but I am unable to do it. The background color is changed through Style class. "DeleteClass" but I am unable to change the text color through same. [image is attached and the background color is as per the class but the text color isn't .](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BdRoN.jpg)

```
 DeleteClass: {
        fontColor: '#ffffff',
        color: '#ffffff',
        fontSize: 20,
        backgroundColor: '#6F1E51'
    },
```

```
 <ListItem text>
           <ListItemText  className={classes.DeleteClass}  primary="Delete"  >

                   </ListItemText>
   </ListItem>
```

Comment: Can you try to remove the quotes? Just color: #ffffff. Also are you using css modules for styling or a style object?

Comment: style object - and without quotes it doesn't work too

Comment: Then instead of using className, I would try to use style={classes.DeleteClass}

Comment: Error: The `style` prop expects a mapping from style properties to values, not a string. For example, style={{marginRight: spacing + 'em'}} when using JSX.
    in div (created by ForwardRef(ListItemText))
    in ForwardRef(ListItemText) (created by WithStyles(ForwardRef(ListItemText)))


i get this error when i use style

Comment: Can you share a little bit more code of the component?

Comment: did you try just doing 'white'

Comment: <List component="nav" className={classes.root} aria-label="mailbox folders">
                    <ListItem text>
                        <ListItemText  className={classes.DeleteClass} color={ 'red'} primary="Delete"  >

                        </ListItemText>
                    </ListItem>
                    <Divider />
                </List>

Comment: const useStyles = makeStyles(theme => ({
    root: {},
    content: {
        padding: 0
    },

    DeleteClass: {
        fontColor: '#ffffff',
        color: '#ffffff',
        fontSize: 20,
        backgroundColor: '#6F1E51'
    },
 
    }
}));

Comment: yes, white doesn't work either-